# Webpack Windows 7 : File watch rebundle work randomly

Tags: webpack

I'm facing difficulties on my js app, packed an ran within a Webpack (with its dev server) that bundles my app : When I modify and save a js file module that is a part of my app, sometimes Webpack performs the rebundle immediatly (as expected), and sometimes it does'nt. In this case, I got to stop the dev server and run it again to perform the bundle action.

Windows version: 7 SP1

Webpack version: 1.13.2 (latest)

my webpack.config:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
        path: './',
        filename: '_index.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 3333
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: [
                        'es2015',
                        'react',
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Anyone has any idea? ._.